# Jquery Hover Affecting All Divs

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have this jquery hover effect, how it works is there is one div that is invisible and when you hover over a div it slides the invisible div up, making it visible. When there are multiple divs and you hover over one div / box.. all the other invisible divs slide up, when just the div you hovered over should slide up.  Here is my jquery for the slide up divs:

```
$(function(){
    $(".video-entry-summary").hover(function() {

        $(".videotntitle").stop(true,true).animate({'bottom': '+=211px' },200);

    }, function() {

        $(".videotntitle").stop(true,true).animate({'bottom': '-=211px' },200);

    });
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem.. and like I said, only one div should be sliding up, not all of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfs6G/1/

Any help would be appreciated!! :)
​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may specify the context to target the right div :

```
$(function(){
    $(".video-entry-summary").hover(function() {  
        $(".videotntitle", this).stop(true,true).animate({'bottom': '+=211px' },200);
    }, function() {
        $(".videotntitle", this).stop(true,true).animate({'bottom': '-=211px' },200); 
    });
});
```

`$(".videotntitle", this)` searches for the elements with class `videotntitle` inside `this` (which is the hovered element)

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DMWhk/)

Comment: worked like a charm!! thanks a lot I'll accept it when I'm able to (in 11 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the wrong selectors instead of the right ones.

You want to target

```
$(this).find('.videotntitle').stop(). etc etc;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfs6G/2/